# Can't find c library for libxml2

Tags: raspbian-jessie, c, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a C program that uses libxml2, it compiles OK (so the C headers are present) but the link fails with the message

```
cc test.o -llibxml2 -lm -o test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibxml2
```

I am using the standard development tools on this OS:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
```

I have already run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

How to I get the C library for libxml2?

Comment: Do you use the *Debian* development tools?

Comment: @Ingo: I have added the details to my question.

Comment: Hmm... you need the packet `build-essential`. On *Raspbian Stretch* it is installed by default. Don't know if also in *Raspbian Jessie*.